# How to access form element in while loop in PHP

Tags: php

i want to get acces to comment and get the value of it , i used $_POST but i get error

**Undefined array key**
the code create photo posts with while loop the post also contains the comment section.

here the Photo post code:

```html
<!-- Photos section -->
    <section>

        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
                <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-1 row-cols-lg-1">
                    <div class="container">

                        <?php

                        if (mysqli_num_rows($res_for_pics) > 0) {

                            while ($pics = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_for_pics)) { ?>
                                <div class="col mb-3">
                                    <div class="card shadow-sm">
                                        <img src="images/user/<?= $pics['pic'] ?>" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">

                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <h5 class="card-title" id="add-com"><?php echo $pics['pic_title'] ?></h5>

                                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $pics['pic_des'] ?></p>
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                                
                                                <small class="text-muted mb-3">by nithan</small>
                                        
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="accordion-item">
                                                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                                                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                <h5 class="card-title"> Comments</h5>
                                                </button>
                                                </h2>
                                                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                                                <div class="accordion-body">
                                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                                  howa
                                                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"></small></p>
                                                </li>

                                            </ul>

                                            </div>
                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
               **I Want to get access to the value of textarea in the other php file**. 
                                            <form method="$_POST" action="../model/comment.php">
                                                <div class="mb-3 mt-5">
                                                    <h5 for="message-text" class="col-form-label">add your comment</h5>
                                                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="message-text" name="theComment"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-light" name="addComment">Comment</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                            </div>


                        <?php  }
                        } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

                    </section>
```

and here comment.php

```
<?php
include('db_con.php');
$comment =  $_POST["theComment"];
echo $comment;
```

So i try to get access to the 'theComment' value from the form .

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not clean enough and I make a guess that you want to import another file of PHP code inside the current one. Did you try `require('comment.php')` ?? This is how you import another script in PHP source code.

Comment: I Want to get access to the value of textarea in the other php file

Comment: Question is unclear but `method="$_POST"` is invalid/incorrect. Method is `POST` or `GET. HTML and PHP are different and have different manuals, PHP superglobals are not the same as HTML values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method

Comment: ^ on the form element, change the method from `"$_POST"` to just `"POST"`.